# Your CAPTCHA is broken

Tags: support

Your CAPTCHA interaction affords no means of validating my humanity.

Here are the steps I take:

1. Load the site. I am presented with a CAPTCHA.
2. I log in to the site using my Google profile. (Foolishly thinking
   this will bypass the CAPTCHA.)
3. I am presented with a CAPTCHA.
4. I supply the captcha terms and click the submit button.
5. I am presented with a pair of text fields: One contains some kind of validation code, the other is blank. I'm instructed to copy from one and paste into the other.
6. I do that.
7. ....profit?

This is not the first time I've seen this modality. I've seen it on other sites, and used it successfully. But on those sites, there's actually a submit button to click. Here, there's not. I have no means of proceeding to the next step.

Comment: Why don't you post some screenshots of this process? Last time I've seen CAPTCHA it was perfectly workable.